# Output sound to specific channel on device

Tags: c#, audio

I have a virtual sound card that has 16 channels. I was wondering if it is possible in .NET to output a sound on a specific channel. So I have one sound going to channel 1, another going to 2 and another going to 3. Thanks!!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Microsoft DirectSound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ee416960%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) is one of solutions of your answer. If you have problem using DirectSound in C# you can see methods of wrappers on DirectShow. [NAudio](http://naudio.codeplex.com/) is reliable and useful project.

And this links is useful for starting:

- [The ultimate Managed DirectSound](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11184/The-ultimate-Managed-DirectSound-9-Tutorial-Part-1)
- [DirectSound using C#, C++ and Visual Basic](http://www.riemers.net/eng/Tutorials/DirectX/Csharp/Series2/tut15.php)

Comment: you can also use ASIO, and any of the other audio APIs that work on windows, although I don't know about the compatibility with C#. To access more than one of these APIs, you may want to use a wrapper such as PortAudio or RTAudio.